# Monodromy Representations

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory

Let, be $V$ a connected   smooth manifold and $q_1,q_2\in V$  and $F:U\to V$ a connected covering  of  degree $d$. This covering induces two monodromy   representations $\rho_1:\pi_1(V,q_1)\to S_d  $ and $\rho_2:\pi_1(V,q_2)\to S_d  $  where $S_d$  denotes the symmetric group of all permutations on $d$ indices.  How to show  that  $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ they are isomorphic, tha is,  exists isomrphims $\phi:\pi_1(V,q_1)\to \pi_1(V,q_2)$ and $ \psi:S_d\to S_d$, such that 
$$\rho_1\circ\psi  =  \phi\circ\rho_2.                    $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a path connecting $p_1$ and $p_2$. This defines an isomorphism  between the fundamental group naturally. Also defines a bijection between the fibers,and this induces a isomorphism among symmetric groups. The isomorphisms satisfies the desired.